# MIT Scheme on the Mac: When I type the single quote key I get an acute accent character

Tags: macos, mit-scheme

I am running MIT Scheme on Snow Leopard. The problem is: when I type single quote (') I get the acute accent character (´) instead. That makes it almost impossible to program in Scheme, because I can't quote symbols, lists etc.

I got MIT Scheme from Mac Ports, but the same thing happens on MIT Scheme downloaded from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/.

---

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under MacOSX
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994,
    1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,
    2006, 2007, 2008 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Friday June 4, 2010 at 2:40:04 PM
  Release 7.7.90.+ || Microcode 15.1 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/C 4.118
  Edwin 3.116
Happy Happy Joy Joy.
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a problem with your system than with Scheme. I know that when I installed it have no problem running MIT on my Macbook. Do you see this issue in other applications like text edit? what application are you writing the code in? Sounds like a simple problem of key bindings but I need more information.